# Play framework javascript routes + non static methods

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.2

Is it possible for Javascript routes be used with non-static controller methods (i.e. route methods prefixed with @ for DI) ?

For example

```
GET     /foo     @controllers.Foo.bar()

...

public static Result jsRoutes(){
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
        // Fails to compile
        controllers.routes.javascript.Foo.bar(),
        // Also fails to compile (cant find symbol JavascriptReverseRoute)
        Router.JavascriptReverseRoute.apply("controllers.Foo.bar",
        "function() {return _wA({method:'GET', url: /foo })}")) 
    );
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. If its impossible then i dont mind using regular ajax but it would be a nice feature to have.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to try not to use Reverse-Routing for the JsRoute and use the relevant direct URLs (for the sake of) to compile the JS out of the controller endpoints and you keep the Controller concrete without Static (hence with DI implemented for the external services).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I've abandoned this idea and went with my "regular ajax" alternative. But if you provide some more details like a code sample, i don't mind testing it and accepting the answer.